# What Happens If the Center of Gravity of a Physical Pendulum is the Same as its Center of Rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I was working in a physics textbook in a chapter about Physical Pendulums and was wondering how a Physical Pendulum would be affected if it was rotating about its center. For example, if you have a uniform thin rod with a pin through its center then you should be able to use the formula:

$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{I}{mgl}}$$

However, if l is the distance between the center of gravity and center of rotation, that will turn to zero because they are the same point. Does this mean that the pendulum won't be able to move, or am I just looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a step back to the differential equation
for the angle $\phi$ of the pendulum.
$$I\ddot{\phi}=-mgl\sin(\phi)$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia around the rotation axis,
and $l$ is the length between rotation axis and center of mass.
(Due to the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) it is $I=I_\text{cm}+ml^2$,
with $I_\text{cm}$ being the moment of inertia around an axis through the center of mass.)

When the pin goes right through the center then you have $l=0$.
That means the differential equation from above becomes
$$I_\text{cm}\ddot{\phi}=0$$

The solution of this differential equation is easy:
$$\phi(t)=At+B$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.
This means your pendulum just rotates with constant angular speed,
instead of oscillating.

Comment: But $I$ scales with $l$ too, right?

Comment: @AlmostClueless Usually $l^2$, but that doesn't change the right side of the differential equation from being $0$

Comment: It does... The equation is actually $m l^2 \ddot{\phi} = mgl \sin{\phi}$. Hence $\ddot{\phi} = \frac{g}{l} \sin{\phi} \to \infty$ for $l\to0$. Which roughly resembles the eigenfrequency going to infinity (the identification is of course only valid in the linear approximation of the potential).

Comment: @AlmostClueless Only in case of a point-like pendulum body it would be $I=ml^2$.
But for an extended body it is $I=I_0+ml^2$ where
$I_0$ is the moment of inertia around its center of mass.

Comment: Ahh, my fault! Rereading OPs question I commit, I thought you were talking about a mathematical pendulum. :)

Comment: But one could maybe include that because of the parallel axis theorem, $I$ in your first equation is not the same as in the second equation. :)

Comment: @AlmostClueless yes, I included that

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about it right. Think of a pendulum as a circular disk on a stick. The pivot is at the end of the stick.

Now shorten the stick to length $0$. That puts the center of the disk at the pivot. The pendulum won't move by itself. It can rotate. As Thomas Fritsch says, it will rotate at constant speed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the rod as the system.
There are two forces acting on the rod which are equal in magnitude because the centre of mass does not accelerate nor move, the gravitational attraction downwards and the force due the pivot upwards.
The torque on the rod is zero so it has a constant angular momentum about the pivot and thus the angular velocity of the rod cannot change.
So in effect the period of “oscillation” is infinite because if the rod starts with a finite angular speed, it continues with that angular speed and never starts moving in the opposite direction.